# Ios url redirect to the app on click using url schemes

Tags: swift, xcode, redirect, deep-linking, url-scheme

I have a email to reset password, on click on that email it should redirect to my app installed on my iphone. I am using url schemes for that. How to direct that reset url to the app to reset password controller.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is opened when you click the URL then all you may want to do next is just parsing that URL to decide which is the target screen to navigate to. Then you can easily use presentational or pushing style to route users to the page you want.

Comment: Asking to redirect the url to app. @congnd

Comment: In order to make your app be opened when tapping custom scheme URLs, you have to register your desired schemes in the Info.plist.

Comment: How to that thing in proper manner, I registered there but not not working properly. @congnd

Comment: You can follow this: https://github.com/kickstarter/ios-oss/blob/6ed3ceaad2daaf54d9a407ba832c5f393a00890e/Kickstarter-iOS/Info.plist

And search for the `CFBundleURLSchemes`